# Java Number Format Exception for Input Strings with Only Digits

Tags: java, string, integer

Many threads on the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` are already existing on StackOverflow. However, none of them seem to answer my problem.

I want to convert the following string to an integer: `idString = "10104102103"`. I tried the following two ways to convert it to an integer

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
Integer id = Integer.valueOf(idString);
```

When executing either one of them, I get the following error:

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10104102103"`.

In other threads, having spaces, NaNs, non-digit characters, and so on were mentioned as reasons for why this error could occur. However, none of these cases are present here.

My questions now are:

- What is causing this error?
- How do I get it working?

Comment: `10104102103` is too big for an int. Use a `long` instead.

Answer (score 3):

What's causing the error is that the number you are trying to parse, `10104102103`, is bigger than the [maximum possible value for an int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), `2147483647`.

It is within the range for a `long`, so you could use:

```
long id = Long.parseLong(idString);
```

However, if your numbers turn out to be too big even for longs, you're left with using arbitrary scale integers, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164407/3890632).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I changed it, but soon found out that Long was also not sufficient. My question has, rightfully, be marked as duplicate, and the referred thread does answer the question. Nevertheless, thank you for your suggestion.